# Views 3, link picture/title to users blog

Tags: views, theming, nodes

I have a view of active blog users and I want to link the title of each blogger to their blog ie /blog/[uid].

By default, it seems views can link the blogger title to their profile ie (/user/uid) but I want to link the blogger title to their blog (/blog/uid)

Any idea of how I can go about this please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out:

- Add field uid to views.
- Go to picture field in views, click rewrite results and output this as link, and then for link path: /blogs/[uid]

Make sure the field uid is visabally above al lthe other field in the view.